# remigration laravel 5 in openshift

Tags: git, laravel-5, migration, openshift, database-migration

When I was working on development, I migrated all of initial project to openshift. After several weeks add more feature, I deleted all tables in my localhost, edit the migration table and rerun the Larevel migration in local.

But now, I am trying to deploy in openshift and found that the table that I edited manually in localhost didnot executed when I push in opensfhift.

And then, I deleted all tables in openshift and push the codes, hopefully that the openshift run all migrations. But unfortunally, it's work.

Have someone experienced in this case? What I am strying to do is rerun all migrations in opensfhit.

Comment: When you deleted all the tables in openshift have you also deleted the migrations table? If so try to access your server and run `composer dump-autoload -o` and then `php artisan migrate`. If you still have your migrations table there, delete it and run the previous commands.

Comment: yes, I deleted all tables including migrations table. as far as I know, laravel will run migration automatically when I push the git to openshift. How to I run dump-autoload and migration command?

Comment: You can `rhc ssh -a app_name` and run the commands. Laravel doesn't automatically run the migrations when you push your code. Unless you are using services like Laravel Forge that already have a default deploy script